# Как добавить ссылку внутри круга SVG

Tags: javascript, html, css, svg, анимация

Я нарисовал круг, используя `svg`. Этот круг имеет эффект `:hover`.
Я хотел бы добавить ссылку внутри круга и для текста ссылки изменить цвет при наведении курсора.

Ниже мой код:

```css
svg#circle {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}

circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 700;
  stroke-dashoffset: 700;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
}

circle:hover {
  fill: pink;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 700;
  stroke-width: 10;
}
```

```html
<svg id="circle">
    <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" stroke="darkblue" stroke-width="3"     fill="green" />
 </svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [How to add a link inside an svg circle](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34968082/7394871) от участника  [@steamfunk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4547885/steamfunk).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/34968082/7394871

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Ответ с динамическим добавлением ссылки

Я думаю, что это сработает:

```html
<svg id="circle">
  <a xlink:href="https://www.google.com" style="cursor: pointer" target="_blank">
    <circle  cx="125" cy="70" r="60" stroke="darkblue" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
  </a>
</svg>
```

*Динамическое добавление ссылки на SVG Circle с помощью JS*

```js
function addAnchor(){
  var dummyElement = document.createElement("div");
  dummyElement.innerHTML = '<a xlink:href="https://www.google.com" style="cursor: pointer" target="_blank"></a>';
  
  var htmlAnchorElement = dummyElement.querySelector("a");

  var circleSVG = document.getElementById("circle");

  htmlAnchorElement.innerHTML = circleSVG.innerHTML;

  circleSVG.innerHTML = dummyElement.innerHTML;
  
}
```

```html
<svg id="circle">
    <circle  cx="125" cy="70" r="60" stroke="darkblue" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
</svg>

<button onclick="addAnchor()">Add Anchor</button>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34968169/7394871) от участника  [@Jyothi Babu Araja](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4355342/jyothi-babu-araja).</sub>

Answer (score 4):

Нужно добавить `<text>` элемент, завернутый в ссылку `<a>`.
***Обратите внимание***, что `<text>` элемент, находящийся поверх круга, заблокирует действие наведения на тексте в круге. Поэтому я обернул все это в группу `<g>` и сделал `:hover` на группу.

```css
svg#circle {
  height: 250px;
  width: 250px;
}
g circle {
  stroke-dasharray: 700;
  stroke-dashoffset: 700;
  stroke-linecap: butt;
  -webkit-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -moz-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -ms-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  -o-transition: all 2s ease-out;
  transition: all 2s ease-out;
}
g:hover circle {
  fill: pink;
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  stroke-dasharray: 700;
  stroke-width: 10;
}
text {
  fill: pink;
  font-size: 24px;
}
a:hover text {
  fill: blue;
}
```

```html
<svg id="circle">
   <g>
  <circle cx="125" cy="125" r="100" stroke="darkblue" stroke-width="3" fill="green" />
  <a xlink:href="https://www.google.co.uk/" target="_top">
    <text x="50%" y="50%" style="text-anchor: middle">google</text>
  </a>
     </g>
</svg>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34968234/7394871) от участника  [@Paulie_D](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2802040/paulie-d).</sub>