# SVG Хочу все и сразу: и цвет менять, и размер, и ссылку ставить

Tags: svg

Есть нарисованные svg-иконки, их нужно представлять на сайте в разных размерах, разных цветах (при ховере) и обернуть ссылкой.

Перерыв кучу всего, пришёл к выводу, что это нереально сделать одновременно.

---

Я могу или прописать ссылку в svg, и получить такое ([codepen.io](https://codepen.io/amigo9876/pen/eYdNXMv)):

```html
<object type="image/svg+xml" data="//badparking.in.ua/tow-truck.svg" width="205" height="205"></object>

<!-- В SVG файле так:

<?xml-stylesheet type="text/css" href="style.css"?>
<svg id="Capa_1" enable-background="new 0 0 511.996 511.996" height="512" viewBox="0 0 511.996 511.996" width="512" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
  <a xlink:href="https://www.google.com/" target="_blank">
    <g>
      <path.....>
    </g>
  </a>
</svg>

-->
```

Ссылка срабатывает только при наведении на линию рисунка, а не на объект в целом.

---

Или же сделать через псевдоэлемент, прописав в css:

```css
a.svg:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
}
```

А в html:

```html
<a href="#" class="svg">
  <object ....></object>
</a>
```

Но тогда теряется возможность использовать ховер.

---

Такое реально сделать? Или можно уже идти резать иконки в 3 размера в формате png?

Comment: Всё, что Вы описали, сделать более, чем реально и, думаю, что к тому же не очень сложно. Если бы Вы развернули вопрос и привели бы проблемный пример с кодом прямо здесь, то уже набежали бы отвечающие. Пока можете глянуть [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/820371/265406) по теме.

Comment: Я не могу вставить сюда код. Стаковерфлоу не подгружает svg файл с сервера, поэтому закинул на кодепен.

По той ссылке что вы привели ничего нового для меня. Ссылка обрамляет svg начертание, но не объект в целом.

Comment: _"Стаковерфлоу не подгружает svg файл с сервера..."_ Это не совсем верно.

Comment: Иконки все монохромные? Есть возможность вносить правки в код стилей и svg?

Comment: Обязательно ли делать вставку svg именно через `<object>`?

Comment: Да, есть возможность вносить правки в код свг и стилей.
Я вставляю через object, потому что по-другому не получается управлять размером и цветом.

Answer (score 0):

Ничего лучше, кроме как сделать дубликат svg файла, изменить его цвет, и направлять на него при ховере, я не придумал.

1. Вставляем svg бакграундом.
2. Обрамляем данный блок ссылкой.
3. Открываем второй svg файл редактором кода, и в тег <svg... > вставляем стиль fill="green".

```css
.truck {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    display: block;
    background: url(https://sp-rent.com.ua/images/tow-truck.svg);
    background-size: 100px 100px;
}


.truck:hover {
    background: url(https://sp-rent.com.ua/images/tow-truck1.svg);
    background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<a href="https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1212498/svg-%d0%a5%d0%be%d1%87%d1%83-%d0%b2%d1%81%d0%b5-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d1%83-%d0%b8-%d1%86%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%82-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%80-%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d1%83-%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c"><div class="truck"></div></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте тег `<use>`:

```
<svg width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><use xlink:href="file.svg#id"></use></svg>
```

То есть, вам нужно убрать ссылку из SVG и перенести атрибут id на уровень ниже, `<g id="Capa_1">`. Как бонус, все svg можно разместить в этом файле, друг за другом и получить svg-спрайт.

```css
a {
  display: block;
}
a:hover svg {
  fill: red;
  transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<a href><svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" enable-background="new 0 0 512 512" height="100" viewBox="0 0 512 512" width="100">
<g id="Capa_1"><path d="m415.237 306.257c4.143 0 7.5-3.357 7.5-7.5s-3.357-7.5-7.5-7.5h-4.535c-4.143 0-7.5 3.357-7.5 7.5s3.357 7.5 7.5 7.5z"/><path d="m99.752 424.058c13.353 0 24.216-10.863 24.216-24.216 0-13.354-10.863-24.217-24.216-24.217-13.354 0-24.217 10.863-24.217 24.217 0 13.352 10.863 24.216 24.217 24.216zm0-33.433c5.082 0 9.216 4.135 9.216 9.217s-4.134 9.216-9.216 9.216-9.217-4.134-9.217-9.216 4.135-9.217 9.217-9.217z"/><path d="m189.364 287.292c-4.143 0-7.5 3.357-7.5 7.5v4.702c0 4.143 3.357 7.5 7.5 7.5s7.5-3.357 7.5-7.5v-4.702c0-4.142-3.357-7.5-7.5-7.5z"/><path d="m338.892 230.451h12.685c4.143 0 7.5-3.357 7.5-7.5s-3.357-7.5-7.5-7.5h-12.685c-4.143 0-7.5 3.357-7.5 7.5s3.357 7.5 7.5 7.5z"/><path d="m338.892 251.652h12.685c4.143 0 7.5-3.357 7.5-7.5s-3.357-7.5-7.5-7.5h-12.685c-4.143 0-7.5 3.357-7.5 7.5s3.357 7.5 7.5 7.5z"/><path d="m338.892 272.853h12.685c4.143 0 7.5-3.357 7.5-7.5s-3.357-7.5-7.5-7.5h-12.685c-4.143 0-7.5 3.357-7.5 7.5s3.357 7.5 7.5 7.5z"/><path d="m484.043 197.261c-3.984-10.55-14.231-17.639-25.499-17.639h-6.472v-13.279c0-15.594-12.687-28.28-28.28-28.28-15.595 0-28.281 12.687-28.281 28.28v13.279h-72.574c-11.192 0-20.299 9.106-20.299 20.299v20.999c0 4.143 3.357 7.5 7.5 7.5s7.5-3.357 7.5-7.5v-20.999c0-2.922 2.377-5.299 5.299-5.299h56.74v69.163c0 7.945 6.465 14.41 14.411 14.41h102.908v71.792h-9.142c-4.143 0-7.5 3.357-7.5 7.5s3.357 7.5 7.5 7.5h9.142v10.186c0 1.391-1.131 2.521-2.521 2.521h-29.07c-8.529-19.243-27.8-32.707-50.167-32.707s-41.639 13.464-50.167 32.707c-15.147 0-32.278 0-47.432 0 0-37.306 0-84.522 0-126.787 0-4.143-3.357-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5 3.357-7.5 7.5v33.385h-6.916c-10.523 0-19.085 8.562-19.085 19.085v19.999h-43.2v-21.921c0-12.995-5.656-24.691-14.633-32.764v-30.932c2.839-1.069 4.861-3.801 4.861-7.013s-2.023-5.945-4.861-7.013v-33.913c2.839-1.069 4.861-3.801 4.861-7.013s-2.023-5.945-4.861-7.013v-45.017c0-16.233-13.206-29.439-29.439-29.439-2.382 0-4.695.292-6.914.828l-35.551-19.819c-3.617-2.017-8.187-.719-10.203 2.898-2.017 3.618-.719 8.187 2.898 10.203l27.954 15.584c-3.358 3.707-5.78 8.273-6.909 13.322l-76.863-42.849 2.021-3.627c1.411-2.531 3.723-4.36 6.511-5.152 2.784-.793 5.717-.451 8.247.959l12.697 7.079c3.618 2.017 8.187.72 10.203-2.898s.72-8.186-2.898-10.203l-12.698-7.079c-6.03-3.362-13.01-4.175-19.651-2.287s-12.15 6.248-15.512 12.278c-18.491 33.171-30.744 55.149-32.661 58.589-2.017 3.618-.719 8.187 2.898 10.203 1.156.645 2.409.95 3.646.95 2.632 0 5.186-1.388 6.558-3.849l3.017-5.411v57.162c0 4.143 3.357 7.5 7.5 7.5 10.778 0 19.548 8.77 19.548 19.548s-8.77 19.548-19.548 19.548c-10.779 0-19.549-8.77-19.549-19.548 0-4.143-3.357-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5 3.357-7.5 7.5c0 19.05 15.499 34.548 34.549 34.548s34.548-15.498 34.548-34.548c0-16.476-11.591-30.294-27.048-33.728v-77.39l5.32-9.542 83.45 46.521v34.665c-2.839 1.069-4.861 3.801-4.861 7.013s2.023 5.945 4.861 7.013v33.913c-2.839 1.069-4.861 3.801-4.861 7.013s2.023 5.945 4.861 7.013v30.932c-8.977 8.074-14.634 19.77-14.634 32.765v21.921h-21.323v-12.042c0-4.143-3.357-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5 3.357-7.5 7.5v12.042h-93.969v-12.042c0-4.143-3.357-7.5-7.5-7.5s-7.5 3.357-7.5 7.5v19.542 33.308c0 15.179 11.924 27.622 26.896 28.462v7.657h-19.396c-4.143 0-7.5 3.357-7.5 7.5s3.357 7.5 7.5 7.5h26.896c4.143 0 7.5-3.357 7.5-7.5v-15.108h3.482c-.306 2.342-.481 4.724-.481 7.147 0 10.612 3.049 20.921 8.817 29.812 2.256 3.477 6.901 4.463 10.374 2.21 3.475-2.255 4.464-6.899 2.21-10.374-4.188-6.455-6.401-13.94-6.401-21.648 0-21.976 17.879-39.854 39.854-39.854s39.854 17.879 39.854 39.854-17.879 39.854-39.854 39.854c-4.663 0-9.232-.799-13.581-2.375-3.896-1.413-8.195.602-9.606 4.495-1.412 3.895.601 8.195 4.495 9.606 5.993 2.172 12.281 3.273 18.692 3.273 30.247 0 54.854-24.607 54.854-54.854 0-2.424-.175-4.806-.481-7.147h46.983v10.376c0 8.815 7.172 15.987 15.987 15.987h104.726c8.815 0 15.987-7.172 15.987-15.987v-10.376h23.056c-.306 2.342-.481 4.724-.481 7.147 0 30.247 24.607 54.854 54.854 54.854s54.854-24.607 54.854-54.854c0-2.424-.175-4.806-.481-7.147h24.864c9.661 0 17.521-7.86 17.521-17.521v-98.88c.002-9.362-2.948-10.662-27.951-79.032zm-192.406 106.116c0-2.253 1.832-4.085 4.085-4.085h6.916v24.084h-11.001zm-87.833-80.132h-28.879v-32.939h28.879zm0-92.47v44.53h-28.879c0-6.186 0-38.13 0-44.53 0-7.962 6.478-14.439 14.439-14.439s14.44 6.478 14.44 14.439zm-28.879 107.47h28.879v21.58c-4.527-1.575-9.383-2.442-14.439-2.442-5.057 0-9.912.867-14.439 2.442v-21.58zm-14.634 63.21c0-16.03 13.042-29.072 29.073-29.072 16.03 0 29.072 13.042 29.072 29.072v21.921h-58.146v-21.921zm-60.539 43.532c-22.368 0-41.639 13.464-50.167 32.707h-21.074c-7.45 0-13.511-6.061-13.511-13.511v-25.808h287.638v39.318c-35.088 0-119.18 0-152.718 0-8.529-19.242-27.8-32.706-50.168-32.706zm223.056 58.083c0 .544-.443.987-.987.987h-104.725c-.544 0-.987-.443-.987-.987v-10.376h94.029 12.67zm92.429 36.626c-21.976 0-39.854-17.879-39.854-39.854s17.879-39.854 39.854-39.854 39.854 17.879 39.854 39.854-17.878 39.854-39.854 39.854zm-4.726-273.353c0-7.323 5.958-13.28 13.281-13.28s13.28 5.957 13.28 13.28v13.279h-26.562v-13.279zm48.033 28.279c5.065 0 9.673 3.189 11.465 7.936l22.879 60.638h-2.05l-20.166-20.167 1.812-1.812c2.929-2.93 2.929-7.678 0-10.607-2.93-2.928-7.678-2.928-10.607 0l-14.23 14.23c-2.929 2.93-2.929 7.678 0 10.607 1.465 1.464 3.385 2.196 5.304 2.196s3.839-.732 5.304-2.196l1.812-1.812 9.56 9.56h-39.319l-4.934-29.764c-2.321-14.009-14.311-24.176-28.509-24.176h-2.188v-14.634c23.346.001 36.18.002 63.867.001zm-63.867 29.634h2.188c6.828 0 12.594 4.89 13.71 11.628l4.527 27.312h-20.425z"/><path d="m415.237 375.625c-13.353 0-24.216 10.863-24.216 24.217 0 13.353 10.863 24.216 24.216 24.216 13.354 0 24.217-10.863 24.217-24.216 0-13.354-10.863-24.217-24.217-24.217zm0 33.433c-5.082 0-9.216-4.134-9.216-9.216s4.134-9.217 9.216-9.217 9.217 4.135 9.217 9.217-4.135 9.216-9.217 9.216z"/>
</g>
<use href="#Capa_1"/>
</svg>
</a>
```